# TRIGGER show two row affected T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql

I would like to get data only once. How to do it? for example only from **first action**

table

```
myTABLE1
(
NAME,
SURNAME,
USERNAME, 
USERDATE
)
```

first action to MyTABLE1

```
INSERT INTO MyTABLE1 
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MyTABLE2
```

second action to MyTABLE1

```
CREATE TRIGGER example on MyTABLE1 AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE    MyTABLE1
SET       USERNAME = 'sysUser1212' and USERDATE = '2004-09-02 00:00:00.000'
```

**I get two row affected into MyTable3 but I would like to get only once**

```
CREATE TRIGGER example2 on MyTABLE1 FOR INSERT UPDATE DELETE
    AS
    INSERT INTO MyTABLE3
    SELECT NAME, SURNAME, USERNAME, USERDATE
    from inserted
```

Comment: Do you know FOR = AFTER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create as INSTEAD OF trigger instead.

Inside you could replace  USERNAME by 'sysUser1212' and USERDATE by '2004-09-02 00:00:00.000' while doing the insertion.

```
CREATE TRIGGER examplex on MyTABLE1 INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
INSERT    MyTABLE1 (USERNAME, USERDATE, NAME, SURNAME)
SELECT
    'sysUser1212'
    , '2004-09-02 00:00:00.000'
    , NAME
    , SURNAME
FROM inserted   


-- The following disapear
/*
CREATE TRIGGER example on MyTABLE1 AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE    MyTABLE1
SET       USERNAME = 'sysUser1212' and USERDATE = '2004-09-02 00:00:00.000'
--*/
```